# AngularJS Controller Access for all views

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm currently working on an AngularJS app and attempting to create a controller with functions to be used throughout the app. Examples of this include a back button, a logout button, and navigation links. However when trying to execute it, it won't work. How would I be able to make it work.

For reference, body starts with

Below is my controller code:

```
angular.module('Squeeg.controllers', [])
.controller('SqueegApp', function($scope, $state, $rootScope, $stateParams) {

  $scope.back = function() { 
    $state.go('welcome'); 
  }; 

  $scope.logout = function() {
    Parse.User.logOut();
    $rootScope.user = null;
    $rootScope.isLoggedIn = false;
    $state.go('welcome', {
        clear: true
    });
 };
 })

.controller('WelcomeController', function($scope, $state, $rootScope, $stateParams) { 

alert("test");

})

.controller('HomeController', function($scope, $state, $rootScope) {

$scope.home = "Home"; 

})


.controller('View2', function($scope, $state, $rootScope) { 

$scope.message = "Test"; 

});
```

Comment: You'll likely want nested views or at least multiple views. Since it appears you're using `ui.router` you should check out https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views

Comment: Make what work specifically? What does `doesn't work` mean?

Comment: You're talking about breaking out pieces of the app into reusable components.  I think what you are looking for is Directives https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: Check out this http://plnkr.co/edit/Q3CgSN?p=preview. It will give you more idea how to achieve this.